# Intellij Idea and Spring Integration: Some Spring beans not found when importing a project

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

I imported a Maven project that uses Spring Integration. The bean "messageBuilderFactory" is defined by Spring and is available context-wide. However, IntelliJ does not resolve it and it shows an error.

```
<beans:bean id="myTransformer" class="com.my.Transformer">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="messageBuilderFactory"/>
</beans:bean>
```

Shouldn't this bean be resolved?

Comment: How did you [configure](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/enabling-spring-support.html) your spring application context `File` -> `Project Structure` -> `Facets`?

Comment: Add Spring Facet and then added all the files available (I had local Spring files and CFX, for instance, but no Spring files from libraries)

Comment: which file is `messageBuilderFactory` defined in? Can you share a screenshot of your Facet definition dialog?